# return a row number from a vlookup in vba

Tags: vba, vlookup

I need to know what code to use in this situation.

I am using vlookup in vba to locate a certain record number.  I then need to know what row number the record is located in.  I have tried the following, but received errors:

```
nRowSavedRecord = [Vlookup(Cells(nRows, nColRecNmbr),Range("RecordInfo"),2,False).Row]
```

This gives me a "`Type Mismatch`" error.

or

```
nRowSavedRecord = Application.vlookup(cells(nRows, nColRecNmbr), Range("RecordInfo"),2,False).Rows
```

This gives me an "`Object Required`" error.

I'm sure whatever I'm missing is simple.
(`nRowSavedRecord` is a `Long`)
Can anyone help?

Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

There are several problems in your question.

- VLookup is not property of Application, but of Application.WorksheetFunction
- VLookup returns value, not reference to a cell, so you cannot get row from it

You probably want to use the Match function, for example like this:

```
nRowSavedRecord = Application.WorksheetFunction.Match(Cells(nRows, nColRecNmbr), Range("RecordInfo"), 0)
```

The last 0 means that this is an exact match. You also have to make sure that `RecordInfo` is a one-dimensional range

Comment: It's quite OK to use `Application.VLookup` in place of `Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup` and can be preferrable depending on how you like to handle cases where the search term is not in the lookup table.

Comment: @martin - This worked perfectly!  Thank you.  :o) - Mary Ellen

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried using the Match function?

http://office.microsoft.com/en-gb/excel-help/match-function-HP010062414.aspx